# Custom highlight lines & code block title shiki

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have a custom code for the function of highlighting strings by numbers in the shiki plugin in the svelte application. In order for the lines to be highlighted in the code block, I write this in the markdown file ```` ```js {1-3, 5} ````. I added a function so that it could be indicated in parentheses next to the name of the block and it would be displayed above the code block ```` ```js {1-3, 5} (src/lib/utils/index.js) ````. The problem is that the output of the code block name works only if you do not register the part responsible for highlighting lines in markdown, that is so
```` ```js (src/lib/utils/index.js) ````. How to fix the following code so that you can use both the block name and the backlight at the same time

```
import { parse } from 'node-html-parser';
import { getHighlighter } from 'shiki';

const THEME = 'github-dark';

/**
 * Returns code with curly braces and backticks replaced by HTML entity equivalents
 * @param {string} html - highlighted HTML
 * @returns {string} - escaped HTML
 */
function escapeHtml(code) {
    return code.replace(
        /[{}]/g,
        (character) => ({
            '{': '&lbrace;',
            '}': '&rbrace;',
            '': '&grave;'
        })[character],
    );
}

/**
 * Returns array of line numbers to be highlighted
 * @param {string} rangeString - range string to be parsed (e.g. {1,3-5,8})
 * @returns {number[]}
 */
function rangeParser(rangeString) {
    const result = [];
    const ranges = rangeString.split(',');
    ranges.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.indexOf('-') === -1) {
            result.push(parseInt(element, 10));
        } else {
            const limits = element.split('-');
            const start = parseInt(limits[0], 10);
            const end = parseInt(limits[1], 10);
            for (let i = start; i <= end; i += 1) {
                result.push(i);
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
}

/**
 * @param html {string} - code to highlight
 * @returns {string} - highlighted html
 */
function makeFocussable(html) {
    const root = parse(html);
    root.querySelector('pre').setAttribute('tabIndex', '0');
    return root.toString();
}

/**
 * @param code {string} - code to highlight
 * @param lang {string} - code language
 * @param meta {string} - code meta
 * @returns {string} - highlighted html
 */
async function highlighter(code, lang, meta) {
    const shikiHighlighter = await getHighlighter({
        theme: THEME,
    });

    let html;
    let blockName = '';

    if (meta && meta.startsWith('(') && meta.endsWith(')')) {
        blockName = meta.substring(1, meta.length - 1).trim();
        meta = null;
    }

    if (!meta) {
        html = shikiHighlighter.codeToHtml(code, {
            lang,
        });
        blockName
    } else {
        const highlightMetaMatch = /{([\d,-]+)}/.exec(meta);
        const highlightMeta = highlightMetaMatch ? highlightMetaMatch[1] : '';
        const highlightLines = rangeParser(highlightMeta);

        html = shikiHighlighter.codeToHtml(code, {
            lang,
            lineOptions: highlightLines.map((element) => ({
                line: element,
                classes: ['highlight-line'],
            })),
        });
        blockName
    }
    html = makeFocussable(html);

    if (blockName) {
        html = `<div class="code-block-title">${blockName}</div>${html}`;
    }

    return escapeHtml(html);
}

export default highlighter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change code

```
import { parse } from 'node-html-parser';
import { getHighlighter } from 'shiki';

const THEME = 'github-dark';

/**
 * Returns code with curly braces and backticks replaced by HTML entity equivalents
 * @param {string} html - highlighted HTML
 * @returns {string} - escaped HTML
 */
function escapeHtml(code) {
    return code.replace(
        /[{}]/g,
        (character) => ({
            '{': '&lbrace;',
            '}': '&rbrace;',
            '': '&grave;'
        })[character],
    );
}

/**
 * Returns array of line numbers to be highlighted
 * @param {string} rangeString - range string to be parsed (e.g. {1,3-5,8})
 * @returns {number[]}
 */
function rangeParser(rangeString) {
    const result = [];
    const ranges = rangeString.split(',');
    ranges.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.indexOf('-') === -1) {
            result.push(parseInt(element, 10));
        } else {
            const limits = element.split('-');
            const start = parseInt(limits[0], 10);
            const end = parseInt(limits[1], 10);
            for (let i = start; i <= end; i += 1) {
                result.push(i);
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
}

/**
 * @param html {string} - code to highlight
 * @returns {string} - highlighted html
 */
function makeFocussable(html) {
    const root = parse(html);
    root.querySelector('pre').setAttribute('tabIndex', '0');
    return root.toString();
}

/**
 * @param code {string} - code to highlight
 * @param lang {string} - code language
 * @param meta {string} - code meta
 * @returns {string} - highlighted html
 */
 async function highlighter(code, lang, meta) {
    const shikiHighlighter = await getHighlighter({
        theme: THEME,
    });

    let html;
    let title;

    const metaMatch = meta && meta.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/); // Ищем название блока кода в круглых скобках

    if (metaMatch) {
        title = metaMatch[1].trim(); // Получаем название блока кода
        const metaWithoutTitle = meta.replace(metaMatch[0], ''); // Удаляем название блока кода из meta
        meta = metaWithoutTitle.trim(); // Устанавливаем обновленный meta
    }

    if (!meta) {
        html = shikiHighlighter.codeToHtml(code, {
            lang,
        });
    } else {
        const highlightMeta = /{([\d,-]+)}/.exec(meta)[1];
        const highlightLines = rangeParser(highlightMeta);

        html = shikiHighlighter.codeToHtml(code, {
            lang,
            lineOptions: highlightLines.map((element) => ({
                line: element,
                classes: ['highlight-line'],
            })),
        });
    }
    html = makeFocussable(html);

    // Добавляем название блока кода перед блоком кода
    if (title) {
        html = `<div class="code-block-title">${title}</div>${html}`;
    }

    return escapeHtml(html);
}

export default highlighter;
```